# Const return type for a view object

Tags: c++

In a code that I work with there is a class which is essentially a vector with metadata. So in the simplest terms, one could say that it is this:

```cpp
class MyVector {
 public:
  explicit MyVector(int size) : data(malloc(size)), size(size), owning(true) {}
  MyVector(char *data, int size) : data(data), size(size), owning(false) {}
  ~MyVector() { if (owning) delete[] data; }

  char &operator[](int);
  char const &operator[](int) const;

 private:
  char *data;
  int size;
  bool owning;
}
```

Then there is a view member function which constructs a view for such a given MyVector:

```cpp
MyVector MyVector::view(int begin, int end) {
  return MyVector(data + begin, size - (end - begin));
}
```

This itself is fine, but there is an attempt to also make a const version of that like so:

```cpp
MyVector const MyVector::view(int begin, int end) const {
  return MyVector(data + begin, size - (end - begin));
}
```

The idea is that the const view cannot be used to modify the elements. But as I interpret it, it doesn't mean anything. The caller can just copy that `MyVector const` into a `MyVector` and change it. Also the `data` member may be constant, but the data it points to isn't. clang-tidy also remarks that the `const` in the return value doesn't serve any purpose.

Am I correct to think that one needs a distinct `MyVectorConstView` type which only allows access via a `char const &operator(int) const` in order to realize a view which cannot change the underlying data?

Comment: The fact that what the data member points to is not const only matters if you have direct access to said data member. Which you don't in your example.

Comment: @super: But I can just copy the `MyVector const` into a `MyVector` and use the `char &operator[](int)` accessor to modify the data.

Comment: Yes, but that's 2 separate issues. One of them is an issue and the other one is not.

Comment: @super there is an `char& operator[]`. Its implementation is not included, but I suppose it does grant access to `data`

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 There's also a `const` overload for the same operator. I'm simply pointing out that if you have a `const` object you won't be able to access the non-const operator and thus have no ability to modify the data.

Comment: @super but the view is not `const`. You can get a `const` view from a `const MyVector`, copy it, viola, you have a non-const `MyVector` with a non-const `operator[]`

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Again, I'm simply pointing out that the issue is the fact that we can create a non-const `MyVector` from a const one. The internal private pointer's const-ness is not an issue.

Comment: @super ok sorry, now I get it. We were looking at the same issue from two different sides.

Comment: But there is no cure to the constness of `MyVector`, right? There is just no way to force the user to always have it as a const object, I need to have a different class?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are correct. Maybe the `const` on the return type was meant as hint to the user, but it is a pretty useless hint, because it goes completely unnoticed when you write:

```
const MyVector my_vector{42};
MyVector view = my_vector.view(a,b);
```

For the same reason we need `iterator`s and `cosnt_iterator`s. It is not sufficient to have  a `const iterator` to disable modifying elements through a copy of that iterator (assuming it does refer to non-const elements).